# Convolution Theorem and Marginal Density Intuition.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

In terms of marginal density, how does one know that summing over the $x$ (or rather along the linear line) values for the joint density of $(x,z-x)$ give us the density function of $z$? 
More importantly, can someone explain this intuitively? (aside from proofs)

[image]

Comment: My answer to this question may be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533145/why-is-the-convolution-output-in-terms-of-t-not-tau/1533414#1533414

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the final formula and seeking intuition rather than thinking about how the formula was arrived at. Indeed, the "thought
process" that your book offers as an explanation of the
formula leaves much to be desired (e.g. it puts *joint density*
in eyebrow-wiggling quotes instead of *sum*). Here is what I wrote in
a previous answer:

Let $Z = X+Y$. For any *fixed* value of $z$,
$$F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\} = P\{X+Y \leq z\}\\
= 
\int\int_{x+y\le z}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx$$ 
and so, using the rule for differentiating under the integral sign 
(see the comments following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77906/15941)
if you have forgotten this)
$$\begin{align*}
f_Z(z) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_Z(z)\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right] \,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,\mathrm dx\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
When $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, the joint density
is the product of the marginal densities and we get the convolution
formula
$$f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f_{X}(x)f_Y(z-x)\,\mathrm dx ~~ \text{for independent random variables} 
~X~\text{and}~Y.\tag{2}$$

---

So much so for the math. What about the "thought process" that
can give an intuitive feel for why the convolution integral gives
the density of $Z = X+Y$? Well, remember that $f_Z(z)$ is a
*density* (measured in units of probability mass/length) and not a
probability. In fact, $P\{Z = z\} = 0$ for all $z$, while
the probability of the event $A$ that $Z$ has value inside
a *small* interval
of length $\Delta z$ centered at $z$ is
$$P(A) = P\left\{z - \frac{\Delta z}{2} < Z < z + \frac{\Delta z}{2}\right\}
\approx f_Z(z)\Delta z.$$
Now, in terms of $(X,Y)$, we have that the event occurs 
$A$ occurs whenever the
random point $(X,Y)$ lies inside a diagonal strip bounded by the
lines $x+y = z + \frac{\Delta z}{2}$ and 
$x+y = z - \frac{\Delta z}{2}$. These lines cross the vertical
axis at the points $(0, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2})$ and 
$(0, z - \frac{\Delta z}{2})$, that is, the *vertical* separation
of the lines is $\Delta z$.

Now, we can find $P(A)$ by dividing up this diagonal strip using vertical lines spaced $\Delta x$ apart, thus creating narrow
parallelograms whose vertical sides are of length $\Delta z$
and are spaced $\Delta x$ apart and whose center is
$(x_i,z-x_i)$. Thus,
$$P\{(X,Y) \in \text{parallelogram}\} 
\approx f_{X,Y}(x_i,z-x_i)\times \{\text{area of parallelogram}\}
= f_{X,Y}(x_i,z-x_i) \Delta x \Delta z$$
so that
$$P(A) = f_Z(z)\Delta z =
 \left[\sum_i f_{X,Y}(x_i,z-x_i) \Delta x\right]\times \Delta z.
\tag{3}$$
The quantity in square brackets in $(3)$ is a sum
(in fact a Riemann sum) and by taking the limit as the
parallelograms grow ever narrower, that sum becomes an integral,
that is, $(3)$ leads to 
$$f_Z(z)\Delta z =
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \, \mathrm dx\times \Delta z$$
thus proving $(1)$. It is in *this* sense that`The pdf of`
$Z$ `is simply the sum of the "joint density" at the points of the line`
$z = x+y$ as your book claims.

Personally, I vastly prefer the  CDF approach over
such messy calculations and inelegant "thought processes"

Comment: Off topic, could we say that $X$ & $Z-X$ are independent?

Comment: Since $Z-X=Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are defined as being independent random variables, yes, **in this problem**, $X $ and $Z-X$ are independent random variables. For _arbitrary_ independent random variables $X$ and $Z$, $X$ and $Z-X$ are not independent.

Comment: i find it rather strange though as $Z-X$ involves the RV $X$...? But i see your point as $Y$ is independent and is defined as $Z-X$.

Comment: How did we know to use the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx$ to find the probability of $Z$? In particular the joint density?

Comment: In addition, WOULD $f_{X,Y}(x_i,z-x_i)\times \{\text{area of parallelogram}\}$ be analogous to density times area = Probability mass for 2-dimensional RVs versus density times length = Probability mass for 1-dimensional RVs?

Comment: "How did we know to use the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx$ to find the probability of $Z$?" Please **look** at the diagram in your question.

Answer (score 1):

if the variables are independent, you have
$$f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_y(y).$$
Hence
$$P(X + Y \le x) = \iint_{(s,t)|s+t\le x} f_X(s)f_y(t)\,ds\,dt
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{x - t} f_X(s)f_Y(t)\,ds\,dt$$
Now differentiate and invoke Leibnitz's rule to get
$$f_{X+Y}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x-t)f_Y(t)\,dt = (f_X*f_Y)(x).$$